# TS newb question: compile error starting Apollo Server trying to resolve promise

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, apollo-server

Hopefully someone can help with this -- I'm trying to start apollo server in a TypeScript project running Express. My app.ts is below. I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2769)
```

I think this has something to do with resolving that last promise to actually start the server. Thanks for answering this presumably very basic question!

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import depthLimit from 'graphql-depth-limit';
import compression from 'compression';
import cors from 'cors';
import schema from './schema';

const corsConfig = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true
};

async function startApolloServer() {
    const server = new ApolloServer({ schema, validationRules: [depthLimit(7)] });
    await server.start();
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors(corsConfig));
    app.use(compression());
    server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    await new Promise(resolve => app.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve));
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
  }
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove validationRules /depthLimit?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks for responding. Yes - same error without the graphql-depth-limit package. VS Code is underlining in red the final "resolve" statement at the very end of the promise., but I still don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Okay can you try await new Promise(resolve => app.listen({ port: 4000 }, (value) => resolve()));

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to match the expected callback signature:

```
async function startApolloServer() {
    const server = new ApolloServer({ schema, validationRules: [depthLimit(7)] });
    await server.start();
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors(corsConfig));
    app.use(compression());
    server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    await new Promise(resolve => app.listen({ port: 4000 }, (value) => resolve(value)));
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!